# Interruptible and uninterruptible sleep

Tags: linux, process

can you tell me some simple example of “uninterruptible sleep” state? I'm learning unix and example with NFS is not much obvious for me.

Comment: What is your experience?

Answer (score 4):

The difference between interruptible and uninterruptible sleep is that the latter ignores signals:

> Linux has two fundamental ways in which a process can be put to sleep. A process which is placed in the TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state will sleep until either (1) something explicitly wakes it up, or (2) a non-masked signal is received. The TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE state, instead, ignores signals; processes in that state will require an explicit wakeup before they can run again.

[Source.](https://lwn.net/Articles/288056/)